# What is best way to learn silverlight?

Tags: .net, silverlight

I would like to learn Silverlight. What books or websites are recommended?

Answer (score 5):

The best places to start are:

- http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/
- http://www.silverlight.net/learn/

For a book:

- http://www.silverlight.net/learn/books/

For questions about Silverlight I would suggest using:

- http://forums.silverlight.net/

Grz, Kris.

Comment: @XIII:  SO not a good place to ask question about Silverlight then?

Comment: Those are great resources and official too.

Answer (score 2):

Once you're true with the basic tutorial stuff, you might also consider following the
[Silverlight Cream][1]
[1]: https://web.archive.org/web/20170226214423/http://www.geekswithblogs.net:80/WynApseTechnicalMusings/Default.aspx
blogposts, which is an aggregate of all interisting Silverlight stuff available on the net.

I am following this one for quite some time now, and I keep on learning very cool new stuff about Silverlight.

Comment: I forgot to mention: in addition to the link above, surely take a look at Tim Heuer's blog here, http://timheuer.com/blog/

Answer (score 2):

We all learn differently, I like books for example, but many of my colleagues do not. I feel that a good book exposes you to the technology as a whole and as you move through the chapters, at least you become aware of the features of the technology.

But I personally think the best way to learn a new tech such as Silverlight or even ASP.NET MVC is by [Problem Based Learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem-based_learning). By this I mean, start with a good, yet basic book and then set yourself a target, a *pet* project or even a proof of concept project at work to highlight what the technology offers. If you can get support from your peers and management even better.

Start basic, and as you think, "damn! oh how do I do this..and that" that becomes your *problem* and you solve using the many resources that we developers have, call it books, colleagues, Google, StackOverflow, other forums etc, the links outlined above. Only having a clear objective, yet realistic I think a technology like Silverlight can be learned to a proficient level.