# How to learn silverlight 4.0

Tags: silverlight

I am trying to learn Silverlight 4.0...i have 3+ years of Exp in .NET but do not know about silverlight...
So request you to suggest me how to start to learn Silverlight 4.0...
I there any good book available in market which teach me or any url...
Also i want some dummy expamples..

Thankx in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012204/what-is-best-way-to-learn-silverlight, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527691/how-to-learn-silverlight-fast and many other posts like those in SO

Answer (score 1):

Google is your best friend.  There are so manny resources available for Silverlight, so that is is impossible to list them all here.  Some of my personal recommendations are

- wrox silverlight 4 book
- Channel 9 has allot of videos
  concerning silverlight
- browse msdn tutorials: 
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163404.aspx
- and last but not lease
  silverlight.net =>
  http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/

And when you think you have a good understanding of the workings of silverlight / WPF you can switch to the MVVM pattern:

http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/04/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.html

Answer (score 1):

Check the official website of SilverLight which is http://www.silverlight.net/.
It contains videos and tutorial that you can start with.